# Decode HTML Escape Characters

Tags: java, android, html, json, google-api

I'm downloading a JSON from the Google Directions API. For the HTML_Instructions field, representing the actual instruction needed for navigation, here is the format:

```
"Head \u003cb\u003esoutheast\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eMinor Ave\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eMadison St\u003c/b\u003e",
```

Is there a way to decode/remove the escape characters from the String that is downloaded in Java/an Android application.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java use

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

In JS use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```js
document.write(decodeURIComponent("Head \u003cb\u003esoutheast\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eMinor Ave\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eMadison St\u003c/b\u003e"))
```

Comment: Is this a method/class that is available in Java, not Javascript?

Comment: Should I use URLDecoder?

Comment: Ooops, yes. I missed the JAVA tag